# How will the static properties work in the queue?

Tags: php, multithreading, static, queue

An example is a class that makes requests using a proxy, but this proxy is set to it in a static variable.

What will happen in the queue? For example, there are 100 tasks that are queued and they are executed in parallel.

Each task sets a proxy for itself and makes requests, will not the proxy property be "overwritten" for each instance when it happens in another task?

```php
class Request {
  private static $proxy;

  public static setProxy($proxy) {
    self::$proxy = $proxy;
  }

  public static doRequest($url, $params) {
    // send a request using a proxy
  }
}
```

```php
// task#1 in queue
class Task {
  public function run() {
    Request::setProxy('someProxyUrl1');
    Request::doRequest(...);
  }
}

// task#2 in queue
class Task {
  public function run() {
    Request::setProxy('someProxyUrl2');
    Request::doRequest(...); // it will someProxyUrl1 or someProxyUrl2?
  }
}

// task#3 in queue
class Task {
  public function run() {
    Request::setProxy('someProxyUrl3');
    Request::doRequest(...); // request using someProxyUrl3 or someProxyUrl1 / someProxyUrl2?
  }
}

// ...

// queue 100
```